# deploying wordpress from google app engine developerment console

Tags: php, python, wordpress, google-app-engine

I am trying to install wordpress in GAE. Currently I am simply deploying wordpress from google's developer console. Now I want to visit my wordpress page by visiting www.mywebsite.com/blog. But google is returning me some external IP(xx.xx.xx.xx), which lands to wordpress page. Is there any way I can change this external ip(xx.xx.xx.xx) to www.mywebsite.com/blog? As this external IP defeats the entire purpose of seo, and doesn't seems right.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You'd want to setup custom domain in that case: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Comment: It's not even entirely clear from this question what you've set up. What DNS records are on your zone file at your domain? What have you done in the Developers Console?

Comment: I have enabled wordpress from developer console. But now I don't know how to map external IP(xx.xx.xx.xx) provided by gae to my site's blog like www.example.com/blog. I don't know to setup zone files, I have the access to my domain. But how to set up zone files and map properly I don't get that.

Comment: @Nick kindly reply, I am stuck with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162010/mapping-wordpress-external-ip-obtained-from-gae-to-my-domain