# mapping wordpress external ip obtained from gae to my domain

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I have deployed wordpress from my google development console, thus obtaining an external ip. Then I already created a URL forwarding address in my gandi.net control panel to that external ip(xx.xx.xx.xx).

And entered the same address(blog.example.com) in my wordpress settings. So now the situation is blog.example.com sometimes work on my system along with some other's, but then it says, "this blog is coming back soon" (dotclear error) for another system.

Can someone point out my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If some more details are required, kindly let me know.

Comment: Are you using GAE or GCE to host your website?

Comment: I am using GAE, and domain registrar is gandi.net

Comment: This seems like a wordpress issue, not a DNS issue, if you can manage to reach your site via a request, regardless of whether it throws an error or not.

Comment: yeah, it was domain issue. Gandi.net helped me with that.

Comment: @Nick and other :Thanks a lot guys, this issue was troubling me like hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Nick. 
"This seems like a wordpress issue, not a DNS issue, if you can manage to reach your site via a request, regardless of whether it throws an error or not."

It would be better if you directly ask your domain registrar for help. Let me know if you require any more help.

Comment: Yes, thanks but this issue was resolved previously. Still up-voting the answer. Thanks.